# How do I get the current edit page ID in the admin?

Tags: functions, admin, id

Most solutions I found are for front-end use. This is for a plugin, so the all activity is in the back-end.

How do I get the page ID that's being currently use(edited) in the admin?

**Note** I'm out of the loop. I just need to get the ID of page(not posts) that I'm currently seeing in the back-end.

Comment: You can get it from URL `wp-admin/post.php?post=14&action=edit`

Comment: I see the URL as a last shot. I hope there is more *elegant* way to do that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can also use

```
$post_id = $_GET['post'];
```

Or you can use a hook (probably better).

```
function id_WPSE_114111() {
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    // do something
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'id_WPSE_114111' );
```

You will need to add a conditional since this will run on all admin pages, I recommend using `get_current_screen();`

For example to run only on *pages*:

```
function id_WPSE_114111() {

    global $my_admin_page;
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( is_admin() && ($screen->id == 'page') ) {
        global $post;
        $id = $post->ID;
        var_dump($id);
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'id_WPSE_114111' );
```

Comment: I need for pages.

Comment: This also works for pages.

Comment: what is `global $my_admin_page;` for?

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code in functions.php file and it will give you a meta box above the publish settings box when editing a post or page.

```
 <?php

function cf_post_id() {
    global $post;

   // Get the data
   $id = $post->ID;

   // Echo out the field
   echo '<input type="text" name="_id" value="' . $id . '" class="widefat" disabled />';
  }

 function ve_custom_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box('projects_refid', 'Post ID', 'cf_post_id', 'post', 'side', 'high');
    add_meta_box('projects_refid', 'Page ID', 'cf_post_id', 'page', 'side', 'high');
   }
   add_action('add_meta_boxes', 've_custom_meta_boxes');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the "most secure" way of checking what the current post is on the post edit (and add) page in wp admin.

```
function wpse114111_get_current_post_id(): ?WP_Post {
    global $post;

        if (empty($post) && array_key_exists('post', $_GET)) {
            $post = get_post($_GET['post']);
        }

        // Optional: get an empty post object from the post_type
        if (empty($post) && array_key_exists('post_type', $_GET)) {
            $object = new stdClass();
            $object->post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
            return new WP_Post($object);
        }

        if (empty($post)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $post;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just use this code in the **functions.php** file, It will give you a current edit page or post ID

```
function get_the_current_page_id(){
$post_id = null;
if( isset( $_REQUEST['post']) || isset($_REQUEST['post_ID'] ) ){
    $post_id = empty( $_REQUEST['post_ID'] ) ? $_REQUEST['post'] : $_REQUEST['post_ID' ];
}
    
//print_r($post_id) For check
//die();
}

//get_the_current_page_id() //Call the function
```