# $current_screen if condition for a specific page in admin

Tags: wp-admin

Right now I have this code to add some changes in my WYSIWYG editor in admin:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'custom_editor_content' );
function custom_editor_content( $content ) {

    global $current_screen;

    if ( $current_screen->post_type == 'page') {
       $content = '

       // TEMPLATE FOR MY PAGE

       ';
    }

    return $content;
}
```

But it's for all pages. I want it only for a page with id = 28. How to do that?

I guess I need to change my if condition to something like:

```
if ( $current_screen->post_type == 'page' && ??? post_id == '28' ??? )
```

However, I need to figure out the code between the question marks.

Comment: `default_content` only runs on `post-new.php`, I presume if you know the page's ID then the page already exists, so that filter won't be applied.

Comment: @Milo so what should I replace it with?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish exactly? do you want to replace the content of the page, or append content onto it? what is supposed to happen if someone changes the content and tries to edit the page again?

Comment: Have a look here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114111/how-do-i-get-the-current-edit-page-id-in-the-admin/114116#114116